# Nonnegative integers represented by $\prod_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} x_j $, where the $a_{i,j}$ are positive integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Fix $m, n \in \mathbf N^+$ with $m+n \ge 3$, and let $A = (a_{i,j})_{1 \le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n}$ be an $m$-by-$n$ matrix of positive integers. What is known about the asymptotic behavior of the counting function of the set, $X_A$, of all nonnegative integers that can be represented by $\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} x_j$ for some $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbf{N}$? (It doesn't make any real difference, but in my notation $0 \in \mathbf N$.)

> Note that I'm essentially looking for references, particularly in relation to the case $m = n = 2$.

*Added later.* To answer @Soufiane Mezroui's comment below: By the "counting function of $X_A$" I just mean the function $\pi_A: \mathbf R \to \mathbf N: x \mapsto |X_A \cap [1,x]|$, and of course I'm interested in the behaviour of $\pi_A(x)$ in the limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: It's probably going to be similar to the behaviour if you look at an arbitrary homogeneous polynomial in n variables of degree n with all positive coefficients, with possibly a scale factor of (det A)^n involved.  Gerhard "Try It With Two Variables" Paseman, 2015.06.04

Comment: What is the exact definition of your counting function of the set of all nonnegative integers that can be represented by this form of degree $n$?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying to the comments. #Soufiane: Let me try to edit the OP and clarify my request. #Gerhard: In fact, I'm mainly interested in the case $n=2$, but I've a feeling that it doesn't make a big difference, and that's why I've phrased the question in its current form. Btw, it is likely that the assumption on $A$ being square and invertible is, on a second thought, completely useless, so I'm going to remove it.